# Javascript: Exposing a global object defined within IIFE

Tags: javascript

I am currently exposing a global object with some common methods that should be accessible globally, but would like to encapsulate its prototype methods definitions in an IIFE mainly to be able to use library aliasing.

To achieve that I currently declare the global object outside of IIFE's scope, and override with a new instance of the object within the scope.

This makes creating a new instance impossible afterwards, which I do not care for. And effectively makes the global object accessible globally:

```js
function CustomNamespace(){};
+function ($) {           
    CustomNamespace.prototype = {
        constructor: CustomNamespace,
        func1: function (args) {
            // ...
        },
        func2: function (args) {
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    };
    CustomNamespace = new CustomNamespace();
}(window.jQuery || {});

// ...

CustomNamespace.func1();
```

Question: is this considered bad practice or anti-pattern ? or is there any other more "elegant" way of doing it ?

PS: I realise this might be a trivial question, but just haven't found any response for this particular case yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
var CustomNamespace = function ($) {
    function MyClass(){};        
    MyClass.prototype = {
        constructor: MyClass,
        func1: function (args) {
            // ...
        },
        func2: function (args) {
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    };
    return new MyClass();
}(window.jQuery || {});

// ...

CustomNamespace.func1();
```